# Angular and ionicPush not working on android

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

Trying to migrate to ionicPush but getting errors anyway I do it:

### Option 1 - Angular  method

When I put `$ionicPush.init` as per guide in the app.js or anywhere for that matter, getting:

`Uncaught TypeError: $ionicPush.init is not a function`

When I check `$ionicPush` it has 2 methods, register and unregister. So clearly it gets imported, but for whatever reason doesnt have `.init`

Top of `app.js` looks like this:

```
.run(function(AppRootService, $ionicPlatform, $ionicPush, $cordovaSplashscreen,$window, $timeout) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    $ionicPush.init({
        "debug": true,
        "onNotification": function(notification) {
            var payload = notification.payload;
            console.log(notification, payload);
              },
        "onRegister": function(data) {
            console.log(data.token);
              }
        });

    $ionicPush.register();
```

### Option 2 - Regular JS way

Put this code in `app.js` after `$ionicPlatform.ready()`

```
var push = new Ionic.Push({
          "debug": true,
          "onNotification": function(notification) {
            var payload = notification.payload;
            console.log(notification, payload);
          },
          "onRegister": function(data) {
            console.log(data.token);
          }
        });

        push.register(function(token) {
          console.log("Device token:",token.token);
        });
        Ionic.io();
```

Still nothing, this time error is `Uncaught ReferenceError: Ionic is not defined`

Ran both of these:

```
ionic add ionic-platform-web-client
ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push
```

Moved around `Ionic.io()`, not luck

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to init io and activate debug/dev mode.

Here is the all steps...

```
ionic add ionic-platform-web-client
ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push
ionic io init
ionic config set dev_push true

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    var push = new Ionic.Push({
      "debug": true
    });

    push.register(function(token) {
      console.log("Device token:",token.token);
    });
  });
})
```

Checkout this page for setting up push for platforms (iOS, Android)
http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-from-scratch

Answer (score 0):

This is the code i use with the [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push)
inside the run phase

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
    var androidConfig = {
        'senderID': '****google-project-id****',
        'sound': true,
        'vibrate': true
    };
    var Push = PushNotification.init({
      "android": androidConfig
    });

    Push.on('registration', function(data) {
        // device token:
        var deviceToken = data.registrationId;
        console.log('pushToken', deviceToken);
    });

    Push.on('error', function(e) {
      console.error('Notifications error: ', e.message, e);
    });


    Push.on('notification', function(response){
      console.log('norification', response)
      console.log('any additinal data the push recieved', response.additionalData)
    });
}, false);
```

try what i did and it will work for you.